# selecting Max from a string and its uniqueness

Tags: php, mysql

how do I generate unique FORM NUMBER

form_no column in my table has this records

```
YU13-23-0004
YU13-24-0025
YU13-24-0026
```

I just tested this
SELECT MAX(form_no) as latestapp FROM app_numbers

but it fetch YU13-24-0025 not 26 because im going fetch its substr(last 4 digit) then +1,
how do I get it and how to make sure other user of my form doesnt get the fetched max.

thanks

Comment: is that a varchar number???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY This!
     select max(SUBSTRING_INDEX(form_no, '-', -1) ) from ;

Comment: but sir how do i get it

Answer (score 0):

```
select max(substring(form_no,'_',8)) from <your_table_name>;
```

Comment: #1305 - FUNCTION hrms.charindex does not exist